# Ubuntu 20.04 Server using a lot of ram

Tags: server, 20.04

Hi I have a Ubuntu server that is installed on a desktop computer, and I noticed  that I am using a lot of ram, and now I am using swap, I don't know what information I should give you so if you ask I will be happy to hand it over.
This is the top command
[image]

I cannot make head or tails of it so...
This is what is making me ask
[image]

Comment: `top` from command line and check what is using RAM.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu Server for server uses?

Comment: I am running a website

Comment: @Rinzwind THis is what I see

Comment: I made a edit that is what I see for the top command

Comment: All looks well. I don't see any problem.

Comment: the new edit made me ask

Comment: Yesterday I hit about 50-60 used RAM